# How to get an integer, not long int in Django

Tags: django, long-integer

ive got this code on my project

```
<p> <li><a href="{% url 'detail' prod.item_code_id %}"> {{ prod.name }} </a></li> </p>
```

and getting this error

"Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"

prod.item_code_id is supposed to return an int but its getting long int.
i tried

```
def get_product_item_code_id(self):
  return range(self.product_item_code_)id)
```

which came from a same question here but im getting [0]. [0,1]. or im using the range wrong?

here is my urls.py for the app inventory

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
  url(r'^(?P<item_code_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='product')
]
```

and here's for the project

url(r'^inventory/', include('inventory.urls')),

Comment: One step at a time: show your `urls.py`.

Comment: You have misunderstood the problem. The type has nothing to do with the error you're seeing.

Comment: You're calling the named url `'detail'` in your template--however your urls.py only has `'index'` and `'product'`. Either change your url's name to `'detail'` or change your template call to: `{% url 'product' pro.item_code_id %}`

Comment: thank you so much for seeing that and im really sorry. its my first framework.